# In AngularJS, how do we decide to have one or more controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Let's say if a page has the left panel with some items to choose from, and the right side having a "cart" panel, then would it be good to have 2 controllers: 1 for the left panel, and 1 for the right panel?

And actually, to share data and be able to use data from both controller, we might set a `<div>` for the left panel and then immediately start another `<div>` for the "cart" (nesting the 2 controllers), so that we can "mix and match" the `itemController.foo` and `cartController.bar` (using the "controller as" syntax).

But in the JavaScript code, if we need to share data, there needs to be either a factory service or using a `$rootScope.sharedData` object.  So, why not use just 1 controller instead of 2 so that data sharing is not an issue?  But let's say if we use 2 controllers, there is a special case with the page if the user is a "company coordinator", so that he or she can make multiple purchases per week (instead of a general user limited to 1 purchase per week), and so we need some special handling in the page, should we actually create another controller called `CompanyCoordinatorController`?

The O'Reilly book AngularJS Up and Running, 2014, says on p. 18:

> An AngularJS controller is almost always directly linked to a view or HTML. We will never have a controller that is not used in the UI (that kind of business logic goes into services).

So it seems like it make sense to have 2 controllers?  Can we say, it is one big view on the page and therefore we use only 1 controller?  Will that be non-modular, and not adhering to "separation of concerns" (of product list vs the cart)?  The question really is, when should we create a controller in an AngularJS page?

Comment: One controller would only really be non-modular if sections of that controller or view would be re-usable elsewhere. You also haven't even mentioned nested controllers so question is really far too broad as well as very open to only opinionated answers

Comment: @charlietfl When I first started programming some 35 years ago, things were also "depends on how you would choose to do it."  And then I took a class in Pascal in college, and all of a sudden, it gave a methodology of "top-down", which is, divide the work into smaller steps, and then implement those steps (as procedures or functions), and if the task is too big, break it down too.  And each procedure or function has it own scope, and try not to use global... [cont'd]

Comment: ... and things became crystal clear.  I think AngularJS probably has something methodology like this, or maybe an experienced AngualrJS person can tell you a way, "as a best practice, it can be done this way..."

Comment: [This style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) might help

Answer (score 0):

> It depends.

Seriously though, it's a design decision that you have to make yourself, your team, and those who will be responsible for maintaining your code after you're gone. It is necessary that you components to be modular? It sounds to me like you've already put a lot of thought into this, but are unsure of the choice to make.

There's not going to be one right answer, and any answers you get here (mine included) are biased, subjective, and may not work for you anyway. My advice is try it one way and see if it works. If not, refactor it. In my personal opinion, I prefer modular components that communicate with each other via a pub-sub service. But again, that may not work for your current project. Think about feasibility, cost, and maintainability when you make your decision.

Cheers!